# SSIS pckage execution from ASP.NET MVC web application running in different virtual machine

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure, ssis, virtual-machine

There are three Azure virtual machines running under same azure account.

**First** VM is Domain controller for second and third VMs.

**Second** VM has Windows Server 2012 R2 operating system. This VM has MS SQL Server 2014 installed and it has all the SSIS packages deployed. Some of the SSIS packages are responsible for moving some files from one folder to another folder inside a network drive which is attached (mapped) to this VM.

**Third** VM has also Windows Server 2012 R2 operating system. An ASP.NET MVC web application is running is this VM and it is responsible to **execute** the SSIS packages which are deployed in **second virtual machine**.

***Problem :*** The web application is able to execute the SSIS packages but the files are not getting moved from one folder to another folder. I looked into package execution log and saw a warning message which is as follow :

> Foreach Loop Container:Warning: The For Each File
>   enumerator is empty. The For Each File enumerator did
>   not find any files that matched the file pattern, or the
>   specified directory was empty.

It seems some permission issue but I am not able to identify the real cause.

Here is the SSIS package execution C# code which I have used in my ASP.NET MVC web application to execute the packages:

```
// SSIS server object with connection
IntegrationServices ssisServer = new IntegrationServices(ssisConnection);
// The reference to the package which you want to execute
PackageInfo ssisPackage = ssisServer.Catalogs["SSISDB"].Folders[folderName].Projects[projectName].Packages[packageName];
// Add execution parameter to override the default asynchronized execution. If you leave this out the package is executed asynchronized
Collection<PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet> executionParameter = new Collection<PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet>();
            executionParameter.Add(new PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet { ObjectType = 50, ParameterName = "SYNCHRONIZED", ParameterValue = 1 });
// Get the identifier of the execution to get the log
long executionIdentifier = ssisPackage.Execute(false, null, executionParameter);
```

***Note :*** If I am executing the SSIS package directly from SQL Server Management Studio then it is working as expected (moving files and other stuff).

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, for the website you are deploying your ASP.NET MVC web application to, check what application pool it belongs to and what the **identity** of the application pool is. The account used as the identity for the application pool needs to have file system level permissions to the paths you are trying to access and move around.